# Which is a correct french translation of "Coming together", "Keeping together" and "Working together"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

I'm trying to translate this quote:

> Coming together is a beginning, keeping together is progress. Working together is success.

but I'm having trouble because I don't know if the literal translation really means the same thing as the expressions — my best effort was this:

> Se rendre ensemble est le début. Rester ensemble est progrès, travailler ensemble est succès.

Reading it though, *“se rendre ensemble”* seems more like meeting up in the mall, whereas the expression in English is more about camaraderie and community, and *“working together”* refers to co-operation rather than literally working together.

Are there better idiomatic French expressions to translate this?

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for a different prosody:

> Se rassembler, c'est un début. Rester ensemble, c'est un progrès. Travailler ensemble, c'est un succès.

Comment: Bien qu'on ne puisse pas toujours tout garder en traduction, cette proposition perd tout de même la répétition systématique de « together ».

Comment: J'ai préféré mettre l'accent sur l'idiomaticité et puis la racine est toujours présente (un [polyptote](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyptote)). C'est l'existence même de *rassembler* qui rend si difficile de trouver une combinaison avec *ensemble* pour le premier groupe verbal.

Comment: Ou, d'un autre côté, c'est *rester ensemble* qui pose problème, si l'on veut garder le parallélisme et proposer des verbes pronominaux comme *Se rassembler, rester ensemble et s'entraider* ;)

Comment: Il y aurait *se maintenir*, mais ça ne fonctionne pas avec *ensemble*...

Comment: Effectivement...

Comment: _s'associer_? Cela installe le rassemblement dans la durée.

Comment: @Kareen : Ensemble, on forme bien un groupe ? Ça permet de [contourner le problème](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4411/1514), je crois.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep the repetition, I suggest this neat trick :

> *Former un groupe est un début, souder ce groupe est un progrès, travailler en groupe est un succès.*

All three verbs going very well with *“groupe”*. It gets better if you remove the verb repetition :

> *Former un groupe est un début, souder ce groupe un progrès, travailler en groupe un succès.*

And the most idiomatic, for me, is :

> ***Former un groupe est un début ; le souder, un progrès ; le mettre au travail, un succès.***

The two commas could be removed to turn the semi-colons into commas, but there will still be pauses there, because of the implicit *“est un”*.

Comment: J'aime bien, +1!

Answer (score 4):

I propose literally *Venir ensemble est un début, rester ensemble est un progrès, travailler ensemble est un succès*.

In spirit I think it's *Se retrouver ensemble est un début*, or *Être ensemble est un début*... next is same literally and spirit.

Answer (score 3):

Moi, je dirais:
Se réunir est un début, rester ensemble est un progrès, travailler ensemble est le succès.